# NSNotfication.addObserver - Update to current Swift Syntax?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parse-platform

Currently following a tutorial, however, some of the syntax is outdated. Basically the code should show and hide the user keyboard. I get some syntax errors with the `addObserver` method and Swift wants me to use key path instead, however, if i use the auto 'fix-it' i get even more errors. Can anyone help me out with this? Thanks!

```
NSNotification.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardwillShow), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, nil)       
NSNotification.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardwillHide), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, nil)


func keyboardwillShow(_notification:NSNotification) {    
    keyboard = (_notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]! as AnyObject).cgRectValue
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) { 
        self.scrolledView.frame.size.height = self.scrollViewHeight - self.keyboard.height
    }
}

func keyboardwillHide(_notification:NSNotification) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) { 
        self.scrolledView.frame.size.height = self.view.frame.height
    }
}
```

I get the debug message: `"Incorrect argument labels in call(have _selector:name, expected _forKeyPath:options:context"`

Comment: You don't add observers to `NSNotification`, you should be adding them to `NotificationCenter.default`

Comment: Isnt NotificationCenter.default not more available in Swift 3?

Comment: It's still available

Comment: you are of course right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function has argument, That is missing when you add it in observer

And you have to use `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver` not `NotificationCenter.addObserver`

```
let selectorForKeyBoardWillShow: Selector = #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillShow(_:))
let selectorForKeyBoardWillHide: Selector = #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillHide(_:))

    // MARK: - Functions
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: selectorForKeyBoardWillShow, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: selectorForKeyBoardWillHide, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}


// MARK: Keyboard Observer
func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
}

func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Im not quite sure why, but i've tried to use NotificationCenter before and it didn't worked. Anyways, thank you!